# Add store value in excel using VBA or formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to add total mark which add value to increment by 1 if i choose drop down list option given if the merit is 1 and if i choose drop down list demerit, the total mark will be subtract by one

[image]

For example :

If i choose Good Work in the data validation list , the total mark will be 1, and if i choose once again good work in the same cell,the total mark will updated into 2.

How do i create this formulae or vba excel?

Comment: Perhaps look at the Worksheet Change event.